# Why messenger application receive messages when app force stopped?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I hope that we cannot receive any messages ,when we force stop the default messenger app in our android device.I force stop default messenger app and sent message to that android device. I get message to that device.why this device receive message?

Comment: Why default messenger app receive message,after it is force stopped from settings. will Brodcastreceiver work after app force stopped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Android 3.1+, a `BroadcastReceiver` will only work after its app was force-stopped if an explicit `Intent` is used to send it a broadcast. Here, by "explicit `Intent`", I mean one that contains the `ComponentName` of the receiver, in addition to possibly other data like an action string.

It is unclear what you mean by "the default messenger app" and "messages". If you mean SMS, I would expect that on Android 4.4+, if the user's default SMS client is force-stopped, it would still get SMS messages, as Android probably uses an explicit `Intent` to talk to it. However, on Android 4.3 and below, I would not expect a force-stopped SMS client to receive messages, as `SMS_RECEIVED` was just an ordinary ordered broadcast then.

Comment: ,I mean SMS app in our android device.

Answer (score 1):

This happens often because there is a service that is listening. The app uses the service to connect with Google Cloud Messaging and receive the messages. You'll need to disable the service. You can view Settings -> Apps, then swipe left to view All or Running and view the services.

Answer (score 1):

Extending a bit further Steve's answer, this is probably an exemplary case that describes why programmers **must** control any `Service`s in their applications. Many people just declare and run them, and then they forget about them. `Service`s run in a different component than the foreground app, so if you 'close' your app but you don't stop the `Service`, it will be still running and that's probably what you're experiencing. However, many people tend to misunderstand this concept. This is a different component, but **not** a different thread nor a different process.

As per the official [Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html):

> A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations (such as MP3 playback or networking), you should create a new thread within the service to do that work. [...]

You don't specify what kind of message system uses your app, but if it is `GCM` (Google Cloud Messaging) or some alike system, it indeed uses a background `Service` to receive notifications from the central server and you're getting them because your foreground app is closed but your `Service` is still running.

To stop a `Service`, you'll need to call `Context`'s `stopService()` method, as defined in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29) prior to stopping your foreground application.